# An extension of Stone duality

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, gn.general-topology, stone-duality

First let me recall Stone duality in terms of propositional logic.

Let $L$ and $K$ be propositional signatures (i.e., sets of propositional variables). Let $T$ be a propositional theory over $L$ and $S$ a propositional theory over $K$. An *interpretation* of $T$ in $S$ is a map $I\colon L\to \{\text{$K$-sentences}\}$ (which extends to a map $\{\text{$L$-sentences}\}\to \{\text{$K$-sentences}\}$, which we also denote by $I$) such that $S\models I(\phi)$ for all $\phi\in T$. Two interpretations $I$ and $I'$ of $T$ in $S$ are *homotopic* if $S\models I(p)\leftrightarrow I'(p)$ for all $p\in L$. Let me denote the category of all propositional theories (over all propositional signatures) and homotopy classes of interpretations by $\mathrm{PropTh}$.

There is a contravariant functor $\mathrm{Mod}\colon \mathrm{PropTh}\to \mathrm{Top}$, which maps a propositional theory $T$ over a propositional signature $L$ to the set $\mathrm{Mod}(T)$ of all models $M\colon L\to \{0,1\}$ of $T$ equipped with the topology generated by the sets of the form
$$\{M\colon L\to \{0,1\}\mid M\models T\cup \{\phi\}\}$$
for each $L$-sentence $\phi$. Stone's duality theorem states two things:

- This functor is fully faithful, i.e., for all propositional theories $T$ and $S$, the canonical map from the set of all homotopy classes of interpretations of $T$ in $S$ to the set of all continuous maps $\mathrm{Mod}(S)\to \mathrm{Mod}(T)$ is bijective.
- A topological space lies in the essential image of this functor if and only if it is compact, totally disconnected, and Hausdorff.

I wonder what happens if we replace the category $\mathrm{PropTh}$ by the larger category $\mathrm{PropClass}$ of propositional classes:

A *propositional class* is a pair $(L, W)$, where $L$ is a propositional signature and $W\subseteq \{0,1\}^L$ is a set of $L$-structures. An *interpretation* between propositional classes $(L, W)$ and $(K, V)$ is a map $I\colon L\to \{\text{$K$-sentences}\}$ such that for each $K$-structure $M\colon K\to \{0,1\}$ in $V$, the induced $L$-structure $IM:=M \circ I\colon L\to \{0,1\}$ is in $W$. Two interpretations $I$ and $I'$ between $(L, W)$ and $(K, V)$ are *homotopic* if for any $K$-structure $M$ in $V$ and all $p\in L$, $IM\models p$ if and only if $I'M\models p$ (i.e., $IM=I'M$). Denote the category of all propositional classes and homotopy classes of interpretations by $\mathrm{PropClass}$.

Note that there is a fully faithful functor from $\mathrm{PropTh}$ to $\mathrm{PropClass}$, sending a propositional theory $T$ over $L$ to the propositional class $(L,\{\text{models of $T$}\})$. In this sense, propositional classes generalize propositional theories.

There is a canonical contravariant functor from $\mathrm{PropClass}$ to $\mathrm{Top}$, sending a propositional class $(L, W)$ to the set $W$ equipped with the topology generated by the sets of the form
$$\{M\in W\mid M\models \phi\}$$
for each $L$-sentence $\phi$.

**Questions:**

1. Is that functor fully faithful? If not, is there a way to make it fully faithful, maybe by replacing the category $\mathrm{Top}$?
2. Can one describe the essential image of that functor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(L,W)$ be a propositional class, so $W\subseteq 2^L$. The topology you assign to $W$ is exactly the subspace topology inherited from $2^L$, where $2$ gets the discrete topology and $2^L$ gets the product topology. So the essential image of your functor is just the subcategory of $\mathsf{Top}$ consisting of all spaces which are subspaces of Cantor cubes. These are exactly the Hausdorff [zero-dimensional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-dimensional_space) spaces (where zero-dimensional means that there is a basis of clopen sets).

I believe the functor $(L,W)\mapsto W$ is faithful, but it is not full. For a counterexample, let $L = \{p\}$, and let $K = \{q_n\mid n\in \omega\}$. Let $W$ be the set containing both $L$-structures, so as a topological space it is a discrete space with $2$ points. Let $V$ be the set of $K$-structures in which exactly one variable $q_n$ is true. As a topological space it is a countably infinite discrete space. Then there are continuum-many continuous maps $V\to W$, but only countably many interpretations of $W$ in $V$ (one for each $K$-sentence).

I think the natural extension of Stone duality here should be a contravariant equivalence between $\mathsf{PropClass}$ and the category $\mathsf{Stone}_D$ of Stone spaces (compact, Hausdorff, zero-dimensional) with a distinguished dense set. An arrow $(X,D)\to (Y,E)$ is a continuous map $f\colon X\to Y$ such that $f(D)\subseteq E$. The functor maps $(L,W)$ to $(\mathrm{Mod}(\mathrm{Th}(W)),W)$, where $\mathrm{Th}(W)$ is the set of all propositional sentences true in every structure in $W$.

The idea is simple: An interpretation of $(L,W)$ in $(K,V)$ is exactly the same data as an interpretation of $\mathrm{Th}(W)$ in $\mathrm{Th}(V)$, with the additional requirement that $I(V)\subseteq W$. By ordinary Stone duality, it corresponds to a continuous map $\mathrm{Mod}(\mathrm{Th}(V))\to \mathrm{Mod}(\mathrm{Th}(W))$. And $V$ is dense in $\mathrm{Mod}(\mathrm{Th}(V))$ (indeed, the latter is the closure of $V$ in $2^L$) and similarly for $W$. To see that the essential image is exactly $\mathsf{Stone}_D$, note that every Stone space $X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathrm{Mod}(T)$ for some $L$-theory $T$. The homeomorphism maps a dense set $D$ in $X$ to a set $W$ of models of $T$, and $T = \mathrm{Th}(W)$ by density.

Comment: Thanks! Is the contravariant functor $\mathrm{PropClass}\to \mathrm{Set}$ (note that I replaced $\mathrm{Top}$ by $\mathrm{Set}$) conservative (i.e., isomorphism-reflecting)?

Comment: You're asking about the functor $(L,W)\mapsto W$, right? So the question is: if an interpretation between propositional classes induces a bijection between the classes, does it have an inverse interpretation?

Comment: The answer is no. Let $L = K = \{p_n\mid n\in \omega\}$. Let $W = \{M_n\mid n\in  \omega\}$ where $p_n$ is the only variable true in $M_n$. Let $V = W\cup \{M_*\}$, where none of the $p_n$ are true in $M_*$. There is an interpretation $(L,V)\to (L,W)$ by $p_n\mapsto p_{n+1}$. The induced function $W\to V$ maps $M_{n+1}$ to $M_n$ for $n\geq 0$ and maps $M_0$ to $M_*$, so it is a bijection. But there is no inverse interpretation, since in such an interpretation, $p_0$ should be true when all of the $p_n$ are false, which is not expressible by a single sentence.

Comment: Topologically, what's going on is this: The ambient stone space is $V = \{M_n\mid n\in \omega\}\cup \{M_*\}$, where each $M_n$ is a discrete point and $M_*$ is a limit point. Now the map $M_{n+1}\mapsto M_n$, $M_0\mapsto M_*$, and $M_*\mapsto M_*$ is continuous, but it has no continuous inverse, since it maps the discrete point $M_0$ to the limit point $M_*$.

Comment: Thanks! "Topologically, what's going on is this: [...]" -- so are you saying $\mathrm{PropClass}\to \mathrm{Top}$ is conservative?

Comment: @LeopSchl Certainly the functor to $\mathsf{Stone}_D$ that I suggested is conservative, since it is an equivalence. Your functor to $\mathsf{Top}$ composes this equivalence with the forgetful functor $\mathsf{Stone}_D\to \mathsf{Top}$ which takes the subspace topology on the distinguished dense set. So the question comes down to this: If $f\colon X\to Y$ is a continuous map of stone spaces, which restricts to a homeomorphism between a dense subspace of $X$ and a dense subspace of $Y$, is $f$ itself a homeomorphism? I don't know the answer off the top of my head.

Comment: @LeopSchl I have a counterexample to conservativity to $\mathsf{Top}$. Let $L = \{p_n\mid n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, and let $K = \{q_n\mid n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Let $W = \{M_n\mid n\in \omega\}$ where $p_n$ is the only variable true in $M_n$, as above. Topologically, this is a discrete space. Let $V = \{N_n\mid n\in \omega\}$, where $q_m$ is true in $N_n$ if and only if $m\geq n$. Topologically, $V$ is also discrete, since $N_n$ is distinguished by $q_n\land \lnot q_{n-1}$.

Comment: Now there is an interpretation $(L,W)\to (K,V)$ by $p_n\mapsto q_n\land \lnot q_{n-1}$, inducing the homeomorphism $N_n\mapsto M_n$ between $V$ and $W$. But there is no inverse interpretation, since $q_m$ should be true whenever $p_n$ is true for *some* $n\leq m$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, and this is not expressible by a single sentence. In $\mathsf{Stone}_D$, we can see that the closure of $W$ has a single limit point (none of the $p_n$ are true), while the closure of $V$ has two limit points (all or none of the $q_n$ are true). The interpretation collapses the limit points, so it is not invertible.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder whether there's another way to make $(L, W)\mapsto W$ into a conservative functor. Here's an idea: we could equip $W$ with a partial order instead of a topology, by setting $M\leq M'$ if and only if for all $L$-sentences $\phi$, $M\models \phi\Rightarrow M'\models \phi$.

Comment: @LeopSchl I'm not sure. But your proposed partial order is trivial: If $M\leq M'$, then for every $p$, if $M\models p$, then $M'\models p$, and also if $M\models \lnot p$, then $M'\models \lnot p$, so $M = M'$.

Comment: Oh yes. On the other hand if we restrict to atomic sentences, the construction isn't functorial.